# All 2sxc Data Missing

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We have a site where all of the 2sxc data just disappeared. The template files were still on the server, but all the modules showed errors and all of the data and views were simply gone.

Have you ever seen this in the past? Any idea what might have caused it?

I did upgrade the modules and the site on 8/28/23 but everything was fine after that. We don't know for sure when it started showing the errors, but we think it was before 9/12/23. During the upgrade, I upgraded 2sxc to 16.01 and DNN to 9.11.2. I didn't encounter any errors during the upgrade and the site looked and worked perfectly fine after that.

I was able to get all the data back. I exported all of 2sxc from a backup we had that was working and imported it into the site that wasn't working. It all looks like it was restored fine.

We are just worried about the cause. Do you think anything could be corrupt or any reason for us to worry about it happening again?

Comment: I can't say we've ever seen this happen before. My guess is the upgrade didn't complete, and some files were missing. Basically you have an App_Data folder in the DesktopModules/ToSexyContent/ which needs to have a bunch of json to work. If it's missing, then the data loaded can't be interpreted. That's my best guess.

Comment: Both the broken site and the fixed site have the same files/folders in the App_Data folder so who knows! We are good to go since the export/import worked. More just curious if you thought there might be other issues. Thanks for the info!